# JWPlayer file path obfuscation hide issue

Tags: path, mp3, hide, obfuscation, jwplayer

I've been trying to use a separate php file for serving the actual mp3 file. So instead of putting actual file path in JWPlayer such as:

```
player.load('http://www.mydomain.com/music/mysong.mp3');
```

I'm wanting to do it this way:

```
player.load('http://www.mydomain.com/serve.php');
```

The code seems simple enough, but it's not working yet. When JWPlayer tries to load the song, I get an error that says:

"Playlist could not be loaded: Playlist file did not contain a valid playlist"

I'm not using a playlist, so I'm not sure what that means.

Here is the code for the two files:

---

### index.php (main file)

```
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
// <![CDATA[
var player = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
jwplayer('track_player').setup({
    flashplayer: "player.swf",
    height: 200,
    width: 375,
    autostart: true,
    controlbar: 'over',
    events: {
        onReady: function(event) {
            player = jwplayer('track_player');
        }
    }
});
});

function loadSong() {
//player.load('http://www.mydomain.com/music/mysong.mp3');
player.load('http://www.mydomain.com/serve.php');
}
// ]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="loadSong()">Load Song</a><br />
<div id="track_player"></div>
</body>
```

---

### serve.php (serve the mp3 file)

```
<?php
$filename = 'music/mysong.mp3';

header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
?>
```

---

If I call the serve.php file via the browser, it serves up the file fine and the mp3 plays within the browser (FireFox tested).

I can't figure out why it doesn't work via JWPlayer, though.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

SOLVED!

'provider' needs to be added to the load() function. So it should look like this:

```
player.load({'file':'http://www.mydomain.com/serve.php','provider':'sound'});
```

I hope this helps someone, as someone helped me.